# Recovering a InnoDB database

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, recovery

I had a problem with our InnoDB database. I tried the

```
innodb_force_recovery = 4
```

option in /etc/my.cnf

MySQL can't be used but runs at 100% CPU. Is it normal? Does it try to recover, or I waste my time waiting for the process to stop using 100%?

It runs since 17 minutes now, the ibdata1 file is about 6Gb.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what was the size of your data file before?

Comment: You should wait. Gigabytes of data take a lot of time to read from, fix and write to disks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't stop on innodb_force_recovery = 4 , try values 5 and 6.

Check the error log too. If it prints something like "Waiting to start purge thread" then add innodb_purge_threads=0 to my.cnf

Then dumps all databases with mysqldump and reload into the fresh mysql instance